# Teradata calling a macro table name

Tags: teradata

I'm aware that we could assign a variable in SAS 
For example %let date1=Mar16;

%put &date1 ;

Proc sql;
Create table temp as
Select * 
From Dd_base.my_table_&date1 ;
Quit;

How can I do this in teradata?

Select * 
From Dd_base.my_table_&date1 ;

I need to pass in a date value in the table name

Is there a way to do this in teradata?

Comment: there's no way of creating a user defined variable in Teradata query.....but most teradata communities suggest to create a temp or volatile table with the value in a single row and reference it in the query .Since you are asking to automate the database name. Even that is not possible

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how to reference the value as a table name?

Comment: the thing is you cant. Thats what i said in my previous comment

Comment: try creating a stored process, as variables can be declared in a stored process in teradata

Comment: If you're using SQL Assistant you can enable *Tools-Options-Query-Allow use of Named Parameters in queries* and then you will be prompted for a value when running `Select * From Dd_base.my_table_?date1 ;`. Otherwise you need Dynamic SQL and this is only available in Stored Procedure.

Comment: Thanks for your answers , I don't have knowledge on dynamic sql . Guess I would need to go study on stored procedure.

Comment: Better check with your DBAs first if they will allow you to create SPs